# UWP Item margin of Carousel Control takes time to update?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using a Carousel control where the ItemMargin is calculated in the back end as follows:

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  x:Name ="DemoControl"
  SizeChanged="SizeChanged"
  mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
<Border Margin="0">
  <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemRotationX="0"
              ItemRotationY="45"
              ItemRotationZ ="0"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              SelectedIndex="4">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

Code behind MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
   private void SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateMargin();
    }
    private void UpdateMargin()
    {
            this.DemoControl.ItemMargin = 500;
    }
 }
```

I have noticed that when the page first loads, the objects are closer but after swiping the control, the distance increases and then remains the same. Is the ItemMargin taking some time to get updated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Item margin of Carousel Control takes time to update?

During the testing, the  margin of carousel could render correct after page fist loaded. We can't preproduce your problem. However I found when your `UpdateMargin` in page `SizeChanged`. Carousel loaded event has not triggered yet. I suppose it will case above issue. In general, if you want to update `ItemMargin` property, we suggest your place it in Carousel loaded event.

```
private void CarouselControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMargin();
}
```

That could make sure ItemMargin property will be available.